# Haskell couldn't match expected type char?

Tags: haskell, input, io, output

What im trying to do is call a function that I have already created into an input output main. The function im calling is a high order function shown below:

```
filmsByFan' f = map title $ filter (elem f . fans) testDatabase
```

This is the part of code thats spiting out the error message whenever I try to call this higher order function:

```
getInt :: IO Int
getInt = do str <- getLine
            return (read str :: Int)

main :: IO ()
main = do putStrLn "Enter 1. Add Film / 2. Display all Films / 3. Display film by Year / 4. Display film by fan / 5. Display film by actor and period / 6. Become Fan: "
          str <- getLine
          if str == "1"
            then do return ()
                else if str == "2"
            then do putStrLn (displayAllFilms' testDatabase "")
                else if str == "3"
                    then do putStrLn "Enter a film year: "
                        filmyear <- getInt
                        putStrLn (filmsByYear' filmyear)  <<< **ERROR HERE** (154:47)
                 else main
```

The rest of the code up until here work perfectly, ie if user enters '2' it will run displayAllFilms function (note the displayAllFilms function is NOT a higher order function)

Is it because the function is 'high order' therefore it will give this error?

```
Coursework v1.hs:154:47:
    Couldn't match expected type `Char' with actual type `[Char]'
    Expected type: String
      Actual type: [Title]
    In the return type of a call of `filmsByYear''
    In the first argument of `putStrLn', namely
      `(filmsByYear' filmyear)'
```

Any help would be much appreciated! thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Expected type: String
```

This means that at this point in the program, ghc expects to find an expression of type `String` (because the first argument of `putStrLn` must be a `String`).

```
  Actual type: [Title]
```

This means that the expression ghc actually found here, `(filmsByYear' filmyear)`, has type `[Title]` (because the result given by `filmsByYear'` is a `[Title]`).

If the expected type and the actual type were the same, there wouldn't be an error.

Presumably you have `type Title = String`, so it's trying to unify `String` with `[String]` which fails. (And because `type String = [Char]`, it's gets as far as trying to unify `[Char]` with `[[Char]]`... which still fails.)

Possible ways to fix this:

- Turn the `[String]` into a `String`, e.g. by using [`unlines`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v:unlines)

  ```
  putStrLn (unlines (filmsByYear' filmyear))
  ```

  You might prefer to use [`intercalate`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v:intercalate) from Data.List, depending on how you want the list formatted.
- Call `putStrLn` on each string in the list in turn, by using [`mapM_`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v:mapM_)

  ```
  mapM_ putStrLn (filmsByYear' filmyear)
  ```

n.b. Neither `putStrLn` nor `filmsByYear'` are higher order functions.